# If $|f|\le g$, and $g\in L(E,\mu)$, then $f\in L(E,\mu)$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $f$ is measurable on $E$, and $E$ is a measurable set. If $|f| \le g$ and $g\in L(E,\mu)$, then $f\in L(E,\mu)$.

I know how to proof this given that $g$ is a general function, which means that $\int_E g^+ d\mu $ and $\int_E g^- d\mu $ are finite, so $\int_E g d\mu $ is finite. Because then since $f^+\in L(E,\mu)$ and $f^+ < g$, we have $\int_E f^+ d\mu < \int_E g d\mu < \infty$. Similarly,  $\int_E f^- d\mu$ is also finite. Thus, $f\in  L(E,\mu)$.

However, I have a hard time proving this given that $g$ is nonnegative. I know that in this case, it is possible to have $g\in L(E,\mu)$ and $\int_E g d\mu=+\infty$. Then how can I show $\int_E f^+ d\mu$ or $\int_E f^- d\mu$ are finite? I don't think they are, and therefore I will fail to show $f\in L(E,\mu)$.

Thanks for your help!

---

Some add-on: On page 314 of Rudin, it says If $f$ is measurable and nonnegative, we define $\int_E f d\mu = \sup I_E(s)$. where the sup is taken over all measurable simple functions s such that $0\le s\le f$. The left hand side of the equation is called the Lebesgue integral of $f$, with respect to the measure $\mu$, over the set E. It should be noted that the integral may have the value $+\infty$. Later when it introduce the Lebesgue integral of $f$, where $f:X\to [-\infty, \infty]$, it says we need to make sure both $\int_E f^+ d\mu$ and $\int_E f^- d\mu$ are finite, therefore in this case $\int_E f d\mu= \int_E f^+ d\mu- \int_E f^- d\mu$ must be finite. But it is my understanding that in the case $f$ is nonnegative, it is possible to have its Lebesgue infinity. Is that correct?

Comment: How could $\int_E g \, d\mu = \infty$? You are explicitly told it is finite given the hypothesis $g \in L(E,\mu)$.

Comment: Thank you Umberto for answering. I added some more at the bottom of my question. Do you mind taking a look at it? basically, by reading Rudin page 314, it says given $f$ is nonnegative, it is possible to have its Lebesgue integral infinity.

Comment: Actually, I think I get it now.. "$\int_E f d\mu$ is a call a Lebesgue integral of $f$ on $E$ with respect to $\mu$" is not same as saying that "$f$ is Lebesgue integrable.."

Comment: By $L$ do you mean $L^1$? If so, $|f| \leq g \implies \int |f| \leq \int g < \infty$.

Comment: Thank you Mason.